# Gulp does not copy files when using base dir

Tags: node.js, gulp

Here's the initial directory structure:

```
./src
./src/test.html
./gulpfile.js
```

The goal is simply to copy "src/test.html" to "build/index.html". I'm using the base `base` option in order to maintain the directory structure relative to `src/` within the `build/` dir.

Here's `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src(['test.html'], {base: './src'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

When I run `gulp`, I get no errors.
    $ gulp
    [15:26:24] Using gulpfile /tmp/testproject/gulpfile.js
    [15:26:24] Starting 'default'...
    [15:26:24] Finished 'default' after 8.02 ms

However, it did not create the `build` directory:

```
$ find .
.
./src
./src/test.html
./gulpfile.js
```

Amy I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gulp.src is searching the file in the folder where the gulpfile.js is.
You should change your task to :

```js
gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src(['src/test.html'], {base: 'src'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

The base parameter is used by gulp.src for calculating the relative paths it has to put in the output stream not for setting its "current" folder for reading the files.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I assumed gulp.src was relative to the given base.